# Perl while loop and die

Tags: perl, while-loop, die

I am newbie learning perl. The question I have is how do I make sure that if the mine is not set, after the while, I need to send an error or exception?

```
while (my ($a, $b) = each %$him) {
    if (($c->{$d}) eq $a) {
        $mine = $b;
    }
}
```

Here I have to return error if $mine is not set.

Comment: And `$c->{$d}` is the "mine"? Where did `$d` come from? You should consider using more appropriate and self-documenting variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That whole `while` loops is unnecessary. You just need

```
die if !exists($him->{ $c->{$d} });
my $mine = $him->{ $c->{$d} };
```

You might prefer

```
# If doesn't exist or isn't defined
die if !defined($him->{ $c->{$d} });
my $mine = $him->{ $c->{$d} };
```

or

```
# If doesn't exist, isn't defined, or is false.
die if !defined($him->{ $c->{$d} });
my $mine = $him->{ $c->{$d} };
```

Comment: how about `not`? it'll become more natural :)

Comment: @loldop, There's a reason people dislike COBOL. Concise, visually distinctive operators are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole loop is somewhat strange, because your loop variables `$a` and `$b` have nothing to do with the variables `$c` or `$d`. Note also that you should not use `$a` and `$b`, because they are reserved for the `sort` function. So, as [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) says, your loop is entirely redundant, unless you made a typo and meant `$b` instead of `$d`.

Assuming `$c->{$b}` is "the mine" and "not set" means "not defined":

```
while (my ($a, $b) = each %$him) {
    unless (defined $c->{$b}) {       # the value for this key is undefined
        warn "Undefined mine!";       # produce warning message
        next;                         # skip to next loop iteration
    }
    ....
}
```

You can also use `die` which produces a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl's [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function, as follows:

```
if (!defined($mine)) {
    # produce error here
}
```